# WCF Cannot Serialize Wrapped Message

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, serialization, soap

In short, I try to build a web service consumer with WCF *manually*; here is the SOAP response:

```
<s:Body xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <AMethodResponse xmlns="http://v_namespace">
        <ReturnObjectHeader>
            <Field5>V5</Field5>
            <Field3>V5</Field3>
            <Field4>V5</Field4>
        </ReturnObjectHeader>
    </AMethodResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Shortly, below is the related part in my C# code (after that I present the trace results):

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "AMethodResponse", IsWrapped = true, WrapperNamespace = "http://v_namespace")]
public partial class ReturnObjectWrapper
{
    private ReturnObject _ReturnObjectHeader;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "ReturnObjectHeader", Namespace = "http://v_namespace")]
    public ReturnObject ReturnObjectHeader
    {
        get { return _ReturnObjectHeader; }
        set { _ReturnObjectHeader = value; }
    }
}

[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
public partial class ReturnObject
{
    private string _Field5;
    private string _Field3;
    private string _Field4;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "Field5", Namespace = "http://v_namespace")]
    public string Field5
    {
        get { return _Field5; }
        set { _Field5 = value; }
    }

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "Field3", Namespace = "http://v_namespace")]
    public string Field3
    {
        get { return _Field3; }
        set { _Field3 = value; }
    }

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "Field4", Namespace = "http://v_namespace")]
    public string Field4
    {
        get { return _Field4; }
        set { _Field4 = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is the trace result:

```
Description: An unrecognized element was encountered in the XML during deserialization which was ignored.
Element: http://v_namespace:Field5
NOTE: Same for Field4 and 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found on [this site](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2010/11/10/WCF_service_namespaces); adding `ServiceBehavior` attribute worked for me, i.e.:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://v_namespace")]
```